# Is there a Linux terminal emulator with equivalent functionality to iTerm2 triggers?

Tags: terminal-emulator

iTerm2 has this really useful feature called [triggers](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-triggers.html).

It means I can set up regex's for anything on the terminal that I want to change the formattting of. For example, I can set the string `Error` to always be changed to red.

I can't find a terminal emulator on Linux that has the same functionality. Does one exist?

I have tried:

1. gnome terminal
2. terminator
3. hyper
4. kitty
5. terminology

Comment: This project might interest you - https://github.com/sickill/stderred

Comment: I'm not aware of any terminal on Linux supporting this out of the box. For VTE (gnome-terminal, terminator, ....) this feature request is tracked at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=788673. If you're not afraid of patching, compiling, installing VTE, and defining the match rules in the source file, then you can find a nicely working proof of concept in that bug entry.